# Ubuntu 14.04 git install problem

Tags: 14.04, git

after sudo apt-get install git:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

after `sudo apt-get install liberror-perl`:

```
Package liberror-perl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'liberror-perl' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: just update the repositories and then try to install the above mentioned packages. If it still shows the error then choose a best download server from software and updates, update repos then install packages.

Answer (score 13):

try

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to meet dependencies

Comment: I met this error when install Ubuntu without Internet connection. So it missing some components and need to by update/upgrade.